# Datagrid filter doesn't work. I doesn't return me any rows or columns

Tags: mysql, vb.net

Good afternoon

I have this code block

```
 Private Sub Cbox_title_operation_SelectedIndexChanged(ByVal sender As System.Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs) Handles cbox_title_operation.SelectedIndexChanged

        Title_operationToolStripTextBox.Text = cbox_title_operation.Text
        FillBy3ToolStripButton.PerformClick()
        cbox_cod_tranche.SelectedIndex = -1
        connection.Close()
        connection.Dispose()
        connection.Open()
        pageAdapter = New MySqlDataAdapter("SELECT DISTINCT ls.cod_tranche As 'Cod. Tranche',  ls.cod_cliente As 'Cod. Cliente',  ls.nocional As 'Nocional',  bi.nome_broker As 'Broker',  ls.data As 'Data Entrada',  ls.ativo_compra As 'Ativo C',  ls.qtd_compra As 'Qtd. C',  ls.preco_compra As 'Preço C',  CONCAT('R$ ', FORMAT((ls.qtd_compra * REPLACE(ls.preco_compra, ',', '.')), 2, 'de_DE')) As 'Montante C', ls.ativo_venda As 'Ativo V', ls.qtd_venda As 'Qtd. V', ls.preco_venda As 'Preço V', CONCAT('R$ ', FORMAT((ls.qtd_venda * REPLACE(ls.preco_venda, ',', '.')), 2, 'de_DE')) As 'Montante V', ROUND((REPLACE(ls.preco_compra, ',', '.') / REPLACE(ls.preco_venda, ',', '.')), 4) As 'Ratio Entrada', ROUND(((ls.qtd_venda * REPLACE(ls.preco_venda, ',', '.')) / (REPLACE(REPLACE(ls.nocional, 'R$ ', ''), '.', ''))) * 100, 2) As 'Percentual Ratio Executado'  FROM long_short_tranche As ls  LEFT OUTER JOIN bi_cliente_broker As bi ON bi.cod_cliente = bi.cod_cliente  WHERE title_operation = '" & cbox_title_operation.Text & "' AND bi.cod_broker = '" & inicial_novo.codigo.Text & "'", connection)
        dataSet = New DataSet()
        pageAdapter.Fill(dataSet, scrollVal, 10000000, "long_short_tranches")
        dg_tranche_hist.DataSource = dataSet
        dg_tranche_hist.DataMember = "long_short_tranches"
        connection.Close()
End Sub
```

That returns me a full historic of the operations. I want to run a second code block that filters the result by costumer code (cod_cliente), Its like this:

```
Private Sub Btn_filtro_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles btn_filtro.Click

        connection.Close()
        connection.Dispose()
        connection.Open()
        pageAdapter = New MySqlDataAdapter("SELECT ls.cod_tranche As 'Cod. Tranche',  ls.cod_cliente As 'Cod. Cliente',  ls.nocional As 'Nocional',  bi.nome_broker As 'Broker',  ls.data As 'Data Entrada',  ls.ativo_compra As 'Ativo C',  ls.qtd_compra As 'Qtd. C',  ls.preco_compra As 'Preço C',  CONCAT('R$ ', FORMAT((ls.qtd_compra * REPLACE(ls.preco_compra, ',', '.')), 2, 'de_DE')) As 'Montante C', ls.ativo_venda As 'Ativo V', ls.qtd_venda As 'Qtd. V', ls.preco_venda As 'Preço V', CONCAT('R$ ', FORMAT((ls.qtd_venda * REPLACE(ls.preco_venda, ',', '.')), 2, 'de_DE')) As 'Montante V', ROUND((REPLACE(ls.preco_compra, ',', '.') / REPLACE(ls.preco_venda, ',', '.')), 4) As 'Ratio Entrada', ROUND(((ls.qtd_venda * REPLACE(ls.preco_venda, ',', '.')) / (REPLACE(REPLACE(ls.nocional, 'R$ ', ''), '.', ''))) * 100, 2) As 'Percentual Ratio Executado'  FROM long_short_tranche As ls  LEFT OUTER JOIN bi_cliente_broker As bi ON bi.cod_cliente = bi.cod_cliente  WHERE title_operation = '" & cbox_title_operation.Text & "' AND bi.cod_cliente = '" & txt_cod_cliente.Text & "' AND bi.cod_broker = '" & inicial_novo.codigo.Text & "'", connection)
        dataSet = New DataSet()
        pageAdapter.Fill(dataSet, scrollVal, 10000000, "long_short_tranches")
        dg_tranche_hist.DataSource = dataSet
        dg_tranche_hist.DataMember = "long_short_tranches"
        connection.Close()
    End Sub
```

The second one returns me nothing. What's wrong with the code?

Comment: I think, once `connection.Dispose()` is called, you can't Open it again. Try to create a new instance.

Comment: Done. But it didnt works

Comment: First thing because you're using string concatenation to build your Where condition, you should inspect the value of the SQL that is being generated and try it in something like WorkBench to debug.  2nd thing, Don't use string concatenations, use parameters, security aside just makes easier to maintain and debug.  Finally, not 100% sure on this but are the query conditions case sensitive?

Comment: I see. How do i use parameters with SELECT? When a use parameters it's in a UPDATE function